# Loopback 3.x - User Role M:M relation though RoleMapping

Tags: javascript, mysql, loopbackjs

I have a custom User, Role and RoleMapping, named AdminUser, AdminRole and AdminRoleMapping. I have populated the db with data, and I am using Mysql and Loopback 3.19. My model configuration is:

```
{
  "name": "AdminRole",
  "plural": "adminRoles",
   ...
  "base": "Role",
  "relations": {
    "users": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "AdminUser",
      "foreignKey": "principalId",
      "through": "AdminRoleMapping"
    }
  },
...
}
```

---

```
{
  "name": "AdminUser",
  "plural": "adminUsers",
  "base": "User",
   ...
    "roles": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "AdminRole",
      "foreignKey": "principalId",
      "through": "AdminRoleMapping"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

---

```
{
  "name": "AdminRoleMapping",
  "description": "Map principals to roles",
  "plural": "adminRoleMappings",
  "base": "RoleMapping",
  ....
  "relations": {
    "principal": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "AdminUser",
      "foreignKey": "principalId"
    },
    "roles": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "AdminRole",
      "foreignKey": "roleId"
    }
  },
  ....
}
```

---

When I try to access `GET /adminUsers/{id}/roles` then I get status error 500

`"message": "Relation \"adminRole\" is not defined for AdminRoleMapping model"`

What is wrong with my setup? I have followed the docs.

Comment: update  "foreignKey" : "" in both `AdminRole ` and `AdminUser ` and try. As its work for in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error, renaming the relation names in the intermediate table, fixed the issue:

```
{
  "name": "AdminRoleMapping",
  "description": "Map principals to roles",
  "plural": "adminRoleMappings",
  "base": "RoleMapping",
  ...
  "relations": {
    "adminUser": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "AdminUser",
      "foreignKey": "principalId"
    },
    "adminRole": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "AdminRole",
      "foreignKey": "roleId"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```